# question about convergence and divergence of $\sum (n-2)^3\,e^{-n(x+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have the problem that I could not see my fails in the my [calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pva6z.png) and why does exists just one right way of showing the convergence or divergence of that formula. the first version is the version of the tutor and the version A and B are my versions. there I get 2 different kinds of results what I don't know why. Could someone take a look about that and tell me where are my fails and maybe could someone explain me why I could not use my forms of results with the imaginary parts in it? thx

[image: calculations]

Comment: Why did you take the logarithm of a series to test for convergence?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Where the indices start  is not clear: is it $n=0$ or $n>0$?

Comment: I edited the title to match your image.

Comment: @PeterForeman yes

Comment: @Bernard yes :) forgot sry.\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} [...]
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing for convergence,
as many initial terms as you want can be ignored.
Therefore,
you need only consider
terms with $n > 2$.

In your answer A,
you should be adding the
$-2n$ term,
not multiplying.

Similarly,
in your answer B,
you should add the terms
so that
$\ln(((n-2)^3)e^{-n(x+2)})
=3\ln(n-2)-n(x+2)
$.

Comment: no you arn't right! today start a new try. \begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ((n-2)^3)e^(-n(x+2))  \equiv ln((n-2)^3)*ln(e^(-nx))*ln(e^(-2n)) \equiv (2xn^2)log((n-2)^3)
\end{equation} and look at that. wolfram alpha throws the same result as i have in  A.

Comment: and ok in version B i have 2 different parts, which is the same what you wrote. but why it is not assimilar to A if i dont did a fail with splitting the e function? $e^(-nx)*e^(-2n)$

Comment: forgot the wolfram alpha algorithm [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln((n-2)%5E3)*ln(e%5E(-nx))*ln(e%5E(-2n)))

Comment: and another information: if you do adding the parts in A why you dont do that for positive parts? why is adding just if you have negative parts?